# JIRA Database Values Plugin custom sql

Tags: jira

The `jira-database-values-plugin-10290.properties` file is:

```
# The database connection parameters

database.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
database.user=...
database.password=...
database.connection.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/jiradb

# Cache Timeout (= 15 minutes by default). The actual db is queried only once and then the results are kept in the cache for the given timeout. Uncomment the line below to change it.
#cache.timeout=900000

# The SQL Query that will be executed on the database

sql.query=select start_date from date_table where personel like (select reporter from jiraissue where pkey like '${jira.project.key}' )

# The column number (starting from 0) that contains the primary key of the returned data.
primarykey.column.number=0
# The pattern that should be used to render the data in view mode. Use {column_number} as placeholders. You can use HTML, but make sure you close your tags properly!
rendering.viewpattern={0}
# The pattern that should be used to render the data in edit mode. Use {column_number} as placeholders.
rendering.editpattern={0}
# The pattern that should be used to render the data in searcher. Use {column_number} as placeholders.
rendering.searchpattern={0}
```

When i mention a specific project key (for example JRA-621  ) as below, it works fine..

```
sql.query=select start_date from date_table where personel like (select reporter from jiraissue where pkey like 'JRA-621' )
```

but when I want to call the current project key value, as below, it does not work :(

```
sql.query=select start_date from date_table where personel like (select reporter from jiraissue where pkey like '${jira.project.key}' )
```

What is wrong in my expression?

```
id    personel    start_date   end_date
==    ========    ==========   ========
0     u.name      2012-05-05   NULL
1     u.name2     2012-04-02   NULL
...
```

Thanks